# How to execute a native Inventor Command?

Tags: add-in, vb.net-2010, autodesk-inventor

First post!!

The code (snippet listed below) compiles, builds, runs without any errors. `MessageBox.Show("New Sketch")` runs without an issue, but `cd.Execute()` does not appear to fire.

When I do a quick watch on 'cd.Execute()' the information displayed reflects that the correct command is being accessed, but nothing happens on screen.

As this is my very first addin to try and write, I'm pretty green behind the ears. I've done some extensive Googling, but apparently I'm googling the wrong terms.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Code Snippet:

```vb
        Private Sub m_Sketch_OnNewSketch(DocumentObject As _Document,
                                         Sketch As Sketch,
                                         BeforeOrAfter As EventTimingEnum,
                                         Context As NameValueMap,
                                         ByRef HandlingCode As HandlingCodeEnum) _
                                         Handles m_SketchEvent.OnNewSketch

            Select Case BeforeOrAfter

                Case EventTimingEnum.kBefore

                Case EventTimingEnum.kAfter

                    Dim cd As ControlDefinition = 
                       m_inventorApplication.CommandManager. _
                       ControlDefinitions.Item("SketchSliceGraphicsCmd")
                    cd.Execute()

                    MessageBox.Show("New Sketch")

                Case EventTimingEnum.kAbort
            End Select
```

Comment: After doing some tinkering, I discovered that the code works as intended when `MessageBox.Show("New Sketch")` is prompted out, or placed before `cd.Execute()`.

Why would Execute not run correctly when messagebox is placed after it runs?

Comment: Here's another example: I've got another sub that handles any `OnActiveCommand` to try and watch for when `PartNewSketchCmd` is used. Using break stops and stepping though the lines, I'm able to see when the `Cmd` is hit, and the `try/catch` code is set to slice graphics, but the screen doesn't update. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have solved the issue by watching a `transaction.oncommit` event handler.